# Wordpress: Slider Triggering Silder and Product Listing Both

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, owl-carousel

Kindly take a look at the website http://firehouse.studio/2MomsF/

It is currently in progress. You can see that the header slider is controlled using "Cookies, Cakes and Casseroles". Similary the listing of the categories is handled right below the header by another set of navigation i.e. "Cookies Cakes and Casseroles".

I would appreciate if you can kindly assist in removing the menu below the slider and have both Slider and Products changed from the Slider Navigation of "Cookies, Cakes and Casseroles".

Appreciate your help.

Header Slider is made uusing Owl Carousel 2. Since it has a lot of code i am just going to paste below the code with which i was able to title each slide and make it work on click.

```
    var main = $( '.main-slider' ).owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:0,
        dots:true,
        nav: true,
        navText: ['',''],
        items:1,
        navSpeed: 500,
        dotsSpeed: 500,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        autoplayTimeout: 10000,
        autoplayHoverPause: false
    });
    setTimeout( function(){
        main.css('opacity',1);
    }, 100 );

    var dotsCount = $('.main-slider .owl-dot').length;

    var dotsW = 78*dotsCount;
    var i = 1;

    /*Maddy Wrote this Code - 12/09/2017*/
    var slidercaption=[];
    slidercaption[1]="Cookies";
    slidercaption[2]="Cakes";
    slidercaption[3]="Casseroles";
    /*Written Code Ends*/

    $( '.main-slider .owl-dot' ).each( function(){
        //$( this ).text( '0'+i++ );
        $( this ).text( slidercaption[i++] );
        //$( this ).text( 'Cookies' + ' ' + 'Cakes' + ' ' + 'Casseroles' + ' ' );
```

}

As for the code that displays the products as per the category here is the code below:

{

```
            <div class="cml-row">
                <div class="product-list">
                    <div class="product-list__filter">
                        <span class="active product-list__tab" data-filter="new"><?php echo esc_html__('Cookies', 'chameleon'); ?></span>
                        <span class="product-list__tab" data-filter="popular"><?php echo esc_html__('Cakes', 'chameleon'); ?></span>
                        <span class="product-list__tab" data-filter="sale"><?php echo esc_html__('Casseroles', 'chameleon'); ?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-list__items">
                        <div class="product-list__wrap new active">
                            <?php get_template_part( 'templates/popular', 'cookies' );?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-list__wrap popular">
                            <?php get_template_part( 'templates/popular', 'cakes' );?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-list__wrap sale">
                            <?php get_template_part( 'templates/popular', 'casseroles' );?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to fix your issue yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a clear outline of the exact issue and a summary of what you tried.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Now here is what i have tried to do this myself. I have already tried to post the link as appeared on the product category display right under the slider but it never helped. The Slider is made using Owl Carousel 2.2.1. Hence i tried to make external links to handle the transition of sliders but that never helped as well. FluffyKitten kindly rest assure that i only ask questions when i am out of the options and i cannot take care of something.

Comment: You should update your question with any additional information in case others miss it in the comments. The reason we need to know what you'd tried is so we don't suggest them to you as solutions, and also so we don't waste time trying them ourselves. However you still haven't give us enough information to help. You need to include the code so people unfamiliar with Owl may be able to help.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. Hope the edited post is better than before. Kindly take a look at it yourself too

Comment: I can see now what you are trying to do. Its going to be very difficult to get the 2 separate plugins (Owl and whatever you are using for the filter) to work together - you will need to find the code that triggers the filter and apply it to the .owl-dot element. A bigger issue is that your .owl-dot elements are hidden on smaller screens, so you are removing the only way you have of filtering the products. I'm afraid I'm not in a position to help, someone else may have suggestions for you.